# Parent Child Relationships with code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I've a requirement where I need to provide the user with a dashboard and 3 links. Each link creates an item in 3 other lists X,Y,Z but reference List A, so creating a relationships.
I plan to create the items using JSOM and add foreign keys X,Y,Z.

Normally, I create lookups but in this case I wont. Is this method the right approach as it doesn't allow any form of integrity as a normal lookup does ?

**UPDATE:** When creating an item in X,Y,Z the lookup(ID) needs to be set automatically to the ID of LIST A. I tried edited the Newform.aspx but it gets messy as all XYZ forms need editing, this is why I've chosen the coded option.

Comment: Best approach is to create look up fields

Comment: Hi When creating an item in XYZ, I dont want the user to pick out the ID from ListA manually, this is why I chose the coded version. The ID needs to be set automatically. Are you saying create a lookup but set with code?

Comment: Any chance of a reply to the updates Ive posted please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use SharePoint Taxonomy Service(MMS).

You can easily build the tree hierarchy there.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424403.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Best solution will always be look up field for this case. If you do not want it, place some event handlers on List, grab the ID and update the required one.

Comment: I dont readily have access to the server, this is why I'm thinking of using client object ??